# @children decorator not working in aurelia for me

Tags: aurelia

I am trying to use the aurelia @children decorator to have all the child element buttons in my parent containers view-model, but that doesn't seem to be working. Does anyone have an example that shows how the @children decorator works?

What I am trying to do is have a parent container element that has a bunch of child elements (buttons) and in the parent container I'm trying to keep track of what buttons have been clicked by having a reference to all the buttons the parent container has so whenever a user clicks a button, I can iterate through the buttons list to see what buttons have already been clicked before.

Currently, the code I have below the page fails to load with a 
es6.promise.js:116 Unhandled promise rejection TypeError:.

Commenting out the

@children('button') buttons;

line allows the page to load normally. Thanks for looking!

app.html

```
<template>
  <require from="./custom-element"></require>
  <my-custom-element>
      <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">On</button>
      <div>
        This div falls back to &lt;content&gt; since nothing more specific chooses it. <br />
        Notice how it is displayed last b/c of this.<br />
        Remove &lt;content /&gt; element in custom element and this won't be used in the rendering of the custom element.
      </div>
      <div class="footer">Footer</div>
      <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Off</button>
  </my-custom-element>      
</template>
```

custom-element.html

```
<template>   
    <content select="button"></content>
    <content select="div.footer"></content>
    <content></content>
</template>
```

custom-element.js

```
import {customElement, children} from 'aurelia-framework';

@customElement('my-custom-element')
export class MyCustomElement {
  @children('button') buttons;
  constructor() {
  }

  bind() {
    console.log(this.buttons);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I found between sync and children examples that I've found.

```
@customElement('my-custom-element')
@children({ name: "buttons", selector: "button" })
export class MyCustomElement {
  bind() {
    console.log(this.buttons);
  }
}
```

There's also an issue for when trying to traverse child elements to find elements.

[Not Traversing Child Elements](https://github.com/aurelia/templating/issues/218)